# Flex & Bison: Printing a parse tree

Tags: syntax, tree, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

Basically, I have an assignment where I need to make a compiler for C-, but we're doing it in 5 steps. One of the steps was to turn the BNF grammar to bison and then print a tree with what has been compiled. Let me explain:

**BNF Grammar**

```
1. program→declaration-list
2. declaration-list→declaration-list declaration | declaration
3. var-declaration| fun-declaration
4. var-declaration→type-specifierID;| type-specifierID[NUM];
5. type-specifier→int | void
6. fun-declaration→type-specifierID(params)compound-stmt
7. params→param-list| void
8. param-list→param-list,param | param
9. param→type-specifierID | type-specifierID[]
10. compound-stmt→{local-declarations statement-list}
11. local-declarations→local-declarations var-declaration| empty
12. statement-list→statement-list statement| empty
13. statement→expression-stmt| compound-stmt| selection-stmt | iteration-stmt | return-stmt
14. expession-stmt→expression;| ;
15. selection-stmt→if(expression)statement| if(expression) statement else statement
16. iteration-stmt→while(expression)statement
17. return-stmt→return; | return expression;
18. expression→var=expression| simple-expression
19. var→ID| ID[expression]
20. simple-expression→additive-expression relop additive-expression| additive-expression
21. relop→<=| <| >| >=| ==| !=
22. additive-expression→additive-expression addop term| term
23. addop→+| -
24. term→term mulop factor| factor
25. mulop→*| /
26. factor→(expression)| var| call| NUM
27. call→ID(args)
28. args→arg-list| empty
29. arg-list→arg-list,expression| expression
```

**File: Project.fl**

```
%option noyywrap

%{
    /* Definitions and statements */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "project.tab.h"

    int nlines = 1;
    char filename[50];
%}

ID      {letter}{letter}*
NUM     {digit}{digit}*
letter  [a-zA-Z]
digit   [0-9]

%%
"if"            { return T_IF;      }
"else"          { return T_ELSE;    }
"int"           { return T_INT;     }
"return"        { return T_RETURN;  }
"void"          { return T_VOID;    }
"while"         { return T_WHILE;   }
"+"             { return yytext[0]; }
"-"             { return yytext[0]; }
"*"             { return yytext[0]; }
"/"             { return yytext[0]; }
">"             { return T_GREAT;   }
">="            { return T_GREATEQ; }
"<"             { return T_SMALL;   }
"<="            { return T_SMALLEQ; }
"=="            { return T_COMPARE; }
"!="            { return T_NOTEQ;   }
"="             { return yytext[0]; }
";"             { return yytext[0]; }
","             { return yytext[0]; }
"("             { return yytext[0]; }
")"             { return yytext[0]; }
"["             { return yytext[0]; }
"]"             { return yytext[0]; }
"{"             { return yytext[0]; }
"}"             { return yytext[0]; }
(\/\*(ID)\*\/)  { return T_COMM;    }

{ID}            { return T_ID;      }
{NUM}           { return T_NUM;     }


\n              { ++nlines;         }
%%
```

**File: project.y**

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    extern int yylex();
    extern int yyparse();
    void yyerror(const char* s);
 %}

%token  T_IF T_ELSE T_INT T_RETURN T_VOID T_WHILE 
        T_GREAT T_GREATEQ T_SMALL T_SMALLEQ T_COMPARE T_NOTEQ 
        T_COMM T_ID T_NUM

%%
program: declaration-list       { printf("program"); }
    ;

declaration-list: declaration-list declaration
    | declaration
    ;

declaration: var-declaration
    | fun-declaration
    ;

var-declaration: type-specifier T_ID ';'
    | type-specifier T_ID'['T_NUM']' ';'
    ;

type-specifier: T_INT
    | T_VOID
    ;

fun-declaration: type-specifier T_ID '('params')' compound-stmt
    ;

params: param-list 
    | T_VOID
    ;

param-list: param-list',' param 
    | param
    ;

param: type-specifier T_ID
    | type-specifier T_ID'['']'
    ;

compound-stmt: '{' local-declarations statement-list '}'
    ;

local-declarations: local-declarations var-declaration
    |
    ;

statement-list: statement-list statement 
    |
    ;

statement: expression-stmt 
    | compound-stmt 
    | selection-stmt 
    | iteration-stmt 
    | return-stmt 
    ;

expression-stmt: expression ';'
    | ';'
    ;

selection-stmt: T_IF '('expression')' statement
    | T_IF '('expression')' statement T_ELSE statement
    ;

iteration-stmt: T_WHILE '('expression')' statement 
    ;

return-stmt: T_RETURN ';'
    | T_RETURN expression ';'
    ;

expression: var '=' expression 
    | simple-expression
    ;

var: T_ID                   { printf("\nterm\nfactor_var\nvar(x)"); }
    | T_ID '['expression']'
    ;

simple-expression: additive-expression relop additive-expression
    | additive-expression
    ;

relop: T_SMALLEQ
    | T_SMALL
    | T_GREAT
    | T_GREATEQ
    | T_COMPARE
    | T_NOTEQ
    ;

additive-expression: additive-expression addop term 
    | term                                  
    ;

addop: '+'      { printf("\naddop(+)"); }
    | '-'       { printf("\naddop(-)"); }
    ;

term: term mulop factor                             
    | factor                                
    ;

mulop: '*'      { printf("\nmulop(*)"); }
    | '/'       { printf("\nmulop(/)"); }
    ;

factor: '('expression')'    { printf("\nfactor1"); }
    | var               
    | call          
    | T_NUM                 { printf("\nterm\nfactor(5)"); }
    ;

call: T_ID '('args')'       { printf("\ncall(input)"); }
    ;

args: arg-list
    |                       { printf("\nargs(empty)"); }
    ;

arg-list: arg-list',' expression
    | expression
    ;
%%

int main(void) {
    return yyparse();
}

void yyerror(const char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", s);
    exit(1);
}
```

**And finally the tree that's asked to be replicated:**

```
program
    declaration_list
        declaration
            fun_definition(VOID-main)
                params_VOID-compound
                    params(VOID)
                    compound_stmt
                        local_declarations
                            local_declarations
                                local_declarations(empty)
                                var_declaration(x)
                                    type_specifier(INT)
                            var_declaration(y)
                                type_specifier(INT)
                        statement_list
                            statement_list
                                statement_list(empty)
                                statement
                                    expression_stmt
                                        expression
                                            var(x)
                                        expression
                                            simple_expression
                                                additive_expression
                                                    term
                                                        factor
                                                            call(input)
                                                                args(empty)
                        statement
                            expression_stmt
                                expression
                                    var(y)
                                expression
                                    simple_expression
                                        additive_expression(ADDOP)
                                            additive_expression
                                                term
                                                    factor_var
                                                        var(x)
                                                addop(+)
                                                term
                                                factor(5)
```

**Sample code in which the tree is based off**

```
/* A program */

void main(void)
{
    int x; int y;
    x = input();
    y = x + 5;
}
```

I've turned the BNF grammar to the actual .y file, but I'm having problems printing out where exactly the messages should go. Usually, a grammar would finish THEN print.

Answer (score 1):

The desired output you present is the result of a pre-order walk of the parse tree.

However, bison generates a bottom-up parser, which performs semantic actions for a node in the parse tree when the node's subtree is complete. Printing the node in the semantic action therefore produces a post-order walk. I suppose that is what you mean by your last sentence.

While there are a variety of possible solutions, the simplest one is probably to construct a parse tree during the parse and then print it out at the end of the parse. (You could print the tree in the semantic action for the start production, but that will sometimes result in a parse tree being printed for an erroneous input. Better is to return the root of the parse tree and print it from the main program after verifying that the parse was successful.)

I don't know where "construct a parse tree" fits in the expected progression of your project. Parse trees are of little use in most applications. Much more common is the construction of an abstract syntax tree (AST) which omits many of the irrelevant details from the parse (such as unit productions). You can construct an AST from a parse tree, but it is generally simpler to construct it directly in the parse actions: the code looks very similar but there is less of it precisely because tree nodes don't have to be built for unit productions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Having a hard time understanding your answer but I'm trying! Could you possibly show me a similar solution to what I need? The project consists of 5 parts, first part was to write some regular expressions in a .fl file, finding "if", "else", ";", ".", etc for C- and returning a sentence "Found an "IF" on line #". Now, second part is to write the bnf grammar(guessing this is the right terminology) in a .y file but now printing that output when finding certain code. I've looked into AST but I don't think that's what I need.

Comment: @pigufilms: if you just print each production in the semantic action for that production, you will find that the production follows its component parts. That's the nature of bottom-up parsing. Perhaps that is what your professor is looking for; I don't know. But if you want to print in the order you indicate, you need to build a tree and then walk it.

Comment: I want to print the order that I'm indicating. Basically, if you look at it closely, whatever grammar it falls in, it will execute a code(in my case, printf) immediately. But I'm struggling with this cause it's not working as I want it to.

Comment: @PiguFilms: It prints in the order I claim it prints because that is the nature of bottom-up parsing. Once you understand why it prints in the order it does, you will understand how bottom-up parsing works. That's a useful lesson. But making it print in the order you want it to print means saving the parse tree. If, as you say, you look at it closely.

Comment: Uh, cannot seem to find a possible answer. Tried saving the parsing tree with different variables and 'making" the tree by my self but no luck. Any hints?

Comment: @pigufilms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247206/bison-how-to-print-a-parse-tree

Comment: Ah, I see. I took a quick glance at it and it makes a bit more sense. I'll fully check it out later! Thanks!