# How to print the generated parse tree using Bison?

Tags: c, bison

I know for sure there is a command for CUP that prints out the produced parse tree.
Is there a similar command for Bison?

Comment: Have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247206/bison-how-to-print-a-parse-tree/10248270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

If you want an AST or parse tree, you are responsible for building it, and the AST node objects should be able to print themselves out, as it were.